# Flood Fill Algorithms - Room Area

Tags: c++, depth-first-search, flood-fill

There is task to calculate the room area in matrix. first inputs are the coordinates of row and column position - the zeros are free space, 1 - are the walls. The problem is that flood fill function gives me Stack overflow exception.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int a[5][5] = { {0,0,1,0,0},
                {0,0,1,0,0},
                {0,0,1,1,1},
                {1,1,1,0,0},
                {0,0,1,0,0},
};

bool vis[5][5] = { {0,0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0,0},
};
int c = 0;

void flood(int row, int col){
    if(row < 0 || row > 4 || col < 0 || col > 4)
        return;
    if(a[row][col] == 0 && !vis[row][col]){
        c++;
        vis[row][col] = 1;
    }
    flood(row-1, col);
    flood(row+1, col);
    flood(row,col-1);
    flood(row, col+1);
}

int main(){
    int row, column;
    cin>>row>>column;

    flood(row,column);
    cout<< c;

    getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't recurse if you hit a field that you already visited.

In your code, that means that hitting the `!vis[row][col]` clause should prevent further recursive calls to `flood`. You can achieve that simply by moving them inside the `if` (or perhaps a bit more clearly, moving everything outside and flipping the condition). This will also prevent the recursion from happening when you hit a wall, but that's *also* what you want.

Comment: I think, it should also be noted that recursive descend in a flood-fill algorithm is generally a very bad idea: It will always tend to fill the entire area in a single, very deep recursion, so if `N` is the width/height of the image, the required stack space is `O(N^2)`. This will segfault very quickly as you move to interesting problem sizes.

Comment: @cmaster Good point. Even a simple queue-based iterative approach would work better. This looks like an exercise, though.

Comment: The recursion depth issue is one which we all will inevitably stumble upon when we actually need to use a flood-fill. So I guess, the question is whether a reader takes five minutes to realize that there is a fundamental problem, or spends half an hour writing a recursive flood fill plus an undetermined amount of time on debugging the segfault before coming to the conclusion that recursive flood fill is a bad idea.  Learning from the experience of others is just so much more efficient than making your own mistakes. That's why I usually prefer to give/receive warning on such inherent problems.